# Do any sea creatures exist in The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Are there any water based creatures in *The Lord of the Rings* aside from the [Watcher in the Water](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Watcher_in_the_Water) who attacked the Fellowship in Moria?

Comment: Discussion [here](http://www.lotrplaza.com/archives/index.php?Archive=archive&TID=156212), but hardly authoritative

Comment: Gollum catches and eats fish as part of his regular diet.

Comment: @SystemDown: Yes, but those were freshwater fish, not "sea creatures".

Comment: What's the scope of Lord of the Rings?  Is it just the books?  Or can it be anything in Middle Earth?  I'm pretty sure there were sea creatures in ICE's Middle Earth Roleplaying (MERP), but I think they're based on the Silmarillion or random notes from JRRT.

Comment: Fish.. We see Gollum gnaw on them in the movies.. Deagol and Smeagol were also fishing, when they find the ring.. It would be pointless to go fishing, if there was no fish in the river.. But I guess you mean dangerous water creatures?

Comment: In the Lord of the Rings, Gandalf mentions that during his fight with the Balrog they were both underwater and among powerful beings: 

> Then we plunged into the deep water and all was dark... His fire was quenched... Far, far below the the deepest dwelvings of the Dwarves, the world is gnawed by nameless things. Even Sauron knows them not. They are older than he...

Later it is mentioned that upon springing out the Balrog again burst into flame, implying that they are no longer underwater. These creatures are waterbased and at least as qualified as "sea creatures" as the Watcher.

Comment: @KeithThompson In The Return of the King, Gollum thinks about what he'll do once he gets his precious back. One of his thoughts was about having "fish, three times a day, fresh from the sea."

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not specifically Lord of the Rings, but definitely Middle Earth; here we go!

The poem [Fastitocalon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastitocalon_%28poem%29) describes a typical myth of sailors landing on the back of a sea creature, and is set in Middle Earth.

The Silmarillion describes great underwater weeds in chapter 3, and the earlier Lost Tales drafts make much reference to Ulmo's "Fishy Car" - so there are definitely salt-water fish in the Lost Tales (Ulmo being the Vala of the oceans).

There are definitely sea gulls - both Tuor and Legolas see and hear them.  Looking at their [diet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gull#Diet_and_feeding), one may reasonably infer that sea creatures most probably exist to form part of it.

...and probably other references to fish that I've missed.

Finally, and given that we have explicit info from Tolkien that Middle Earth is *our* world, at an earlier stage of its history (see Letters for more on this), and also given that we have plenty of fossil record for sea creatures going back millions of years, we can quite reliably say that sea creatures *do* exist in Middle Earth.

Comment: Well done.  Didn't have my copy of the Silmarillion at hand, but you covered this better than I could have.

Comment: Quoting from the lotrplaza thread linked in comments to the question: "*we know that the ship of Aldarion was called Hirilondë, but another name for it is the Wooden Whale, and that strongly suggests that there were in fact whales in ME*".

Comment: We may also assume that the inhabitants of the Forochel region have a typical sub-arctic/arctic diet - lots of fish, seals, etc.

Comment: Silmarillion: Ulumuri: Ulmo's conch horn made of shell. Olwe's mansion was made of Pearls. Uinen, the wife of Osse: "all creatures she loves that live in the salt streams"

Comment: @horatio - good catch! ;)

Answer (score 32):

Going by just *The Lord of the Rings*, the answer still appears to be "yes": in "The Council of Elrond" (Book 2, chapter II), Glorfindel at one point suggests throwing the Ring into the deeps:

> ‘... in the Sea it would be safe.’
>
> ‘Not safe for ever,’ said Gandalf.  ‘**There are many things in the deep waters**; ...’